# Hibernate 5 select from table

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate 5 (I am not familiar with hibernate, just started with it) and I want to perform a simple select query, after searching I found the following code to select an element by id:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Ord> query = cb.createQuery(MyClass.class);
    Root<Ord> root = query.from(MyClass.class);
    query.select(root);

    query.where(cb.equal(root.get(MyClass.NUM),ordId));

    Query<Ord> sessionQuery = session.createQuery(query);
    return sessionQuery.getSingleResult();
```

I find it a heavy way to just get just one element.

The question is: Is the above the recommended/correct way to fetch data using hibernate (5)?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL provides us with a quicker and simpler implementation while using the Criteria API is more dynamic and robust.

```
public List<Student> findAllStudentsWithJpql() {
    return session.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Student a", Student.class).getResultList();      
}
```

You are using Criteria API

The Criteria API provides a dynamic approach for building JPA queries.

```
public List<Student> findAllStudentsWithCriteriaQuery() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Student> cq = cb.createQuery(Student.class);
    Root<Student> rootEntry = cq.from(Student.class);
    CriteriaQuery<Student> all = cq.select(rootEntry);
 
    TypedQuery<Student> allQuery = session.createQuery(all);
    return allQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Above two methods are the common way in Hibernate.

Documentation - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can perform something like this...

```
  @Autowired
private SessionFactory session;
Query<Your Class> query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select * from <tableName>);
```